# Looking for workaround to IF function character limitation in a TEXTJOIN formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a simple TEXTJOIN formula with an IF statement that works fine unless any cell text is greater than 256 characters (IF function limitation). I can't think of a workaround.

[image]

In the linked example, the formula will join the text (student comments) in E5 and E10 (based on the value of 8 in col A), as long as the the text in each cell does not exceed 256 characters. However, the text in E10 is greater than 256 characters. Consequently, the formula results in #VALUE!. Some comments are as much as 800 characters (with spaces).

Comment: Sidenote, but did you meant to tag ExcelO365 or Excel2019? Excel 2016 does *not* support `TEXTJOIN()`.

Comment: User defined function may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the limitation of `IF`, but having access to ExcelO365, your workaround would now be:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",,FILTER(E1:E10,A1:A10=8))
```

Comment: That's the trick! I was unaware of the FILTER function and had not seen that combination on my web search. Thank you JvdV!!!